# Create a bash script to create a file always starting with the same first line

Tags: bash

Good day,

I would like to create a bash script which would allow me to always start with the same line, but taking as argument the name of the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
read $name
echo "#!/env/bin/python3" > $name
```

I tried few codes like this one without success.
I want to be able to change the name of the file every time I execute this script.

Comment: Change read statement from `read $name` to `read name`

Comment: If you are planning to edit the file afterwards manually, you should better take some precaution for the case that you invoke the script later again with the same name and erase your previous file. In the simplest case, don't recreate the file if it already exists. A more sophisticated solution would be to have your script examine the file (in the case that exists already) and automatically inserts a missing `#!` line.

Comment: BTW, are you sure that **that** #! line is correct? `/env/bin` seems to me a **very** unusual path.....

Comment: Are you trying to pass the filename as an argument, or as input after running the script? `read` doesn't deal with arguments, it reads input as the script runs.

Comment: @Ivan Thanks for that :) , solution was way simpler than everything I tried..

Comment: @user1934428 yeah you're right I will try to do that. Yeah this shebang is required by my school.

Comment: @GordonDavisson didn't find the function that allow me to use an argument and do everything I wish yet, so I used read instead.
Thanks for your replies guys !!

Comment: I just found out how to get the file_name as argument instead of put in as input after running the script:
    
<pre>
                    <code>#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"

if [ -f "$1" ]
then
    echo "This file already exist"
else
    echo "#!/env/bin/python3" > "$1"
fi</code>
                </pre>

Comment: Well I tried to indent the my code in comment using CTRL + K or <pre> <code> but it doesn't seems to work.. If you know how to do it I will be very grateful